# React - State is defined in one parent function, but not in the other parent function being called from the child

Tags: reactjs, function, class, components, state

I'm re-learning React, and trying to build a simple TODO app, that you can add and remove items from.

My problem is when calling `handleRemove()`. Both functions are in my parent component, and I'm able to pass down `handleRemove()` to my child component. But when I try to setState in handleRemove, it comes up as undefined. I'm not sure why, seeing that it is almost the same as `handleAdd()`

This is my Todo:

```
import React from 'react';
import List from './List';

export default class Todo extends React.Component{

        state= {
            listItems: [],
            count: 0
        }    

    
    handleAdd = (itemToAdd) =>{
        document.querySelector("#input").textContent="";


        this.setState(prevState => ({
            listItems: [...prevState.listItems, itemToAdd],
            count: prevState.count+1
        }))
    }


    handleRemove = (itemToRemove) =>{
        

        let newListItems = this.state.listItems;
        let indexOfRemove = newListItems.indexOf(itemToRemove);
        newListItems.splice(indexOfRemove, 1);


        console.log(newListItems);

        //Setting listItems to the newly created newListItems
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            listItems: newListItems,
            count: prevState.count-1
        }))
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <p>Number of items: {this.state.count}</p>
                <input type="text" id="input"/>
                <button onClick={() => this.handleAdd(document.querySelector("#input").value)}>Add</button> 
                <List removeHandle={this.handleRemove} items={this.state.listItems}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is my List:

```
import React from 'react';

function List(props){
        console.log(props); // props all show up as they're supposed to here
        
        return(
            <ol>
                {
                    props.items.map((item, index) => {
                        return(
                            <div key={index}>
                                <li key={index}>{item}</li>
                                <button onClick={() => props.removeHandle(item)}>Remove from list</button>
                            </div>
                            
                        );
                    })
                }
            </ol>
        )
    }
export default List;
```

I feel like this is something obvious, but I've looked and can't find any clear answer

Comment: You missed binding `this` to your `handleAdd` and `handleRemove` functions, so `this` for the `this.setState` isn't the `this` of the parent component when accessed from children. You can do this either in a constructor or simply convert them to be arrow functions.

Comment: Awesome, great clarification of why binding is necessary, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alright, just found the solution 5 minutes after posting this, ***classic***.

I'll keep this up for any beginners who are confused when trying to keep all state logic in the correct place.

The problem is that when passing down the `handleRemove()` to my `List`, I needed to add .`bind(this)`, like such:

```
<List removeHandle={this.handleRemove.bind(this)} items={this.state.listItems}/>
```

Not exactly sure why it's needed, but i'll be looking into it.

If somebody knows why `.bind()` is needed, feel free to leave a comment

Update: See above comment

Comment: For beginners, don't bind functions like this, use arrow functions, look at docs FAQ for how to bind methods in class components.